# Why @ManyToMany in DB get multi object response?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 tables with many to many relationships
[image]

My code config hibertnate in class Appointment

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_appointment", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "app_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") })
    private List<Student> clients;
```

I added 3 record in table student_appointment with 1 appointment and 3 client.
after I call :

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Appointment.class)
                    .add((Criterion) Restrictions.between("startDate", startDate, endDate));

cr.list();
```

I want 1 appointment with list 3 students. however result is 3 appointments. a appointment have 3 students. what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Maybe nothing is wrong with the query. It depends on what the database content is.

Comment: At least in cases where `JOIN FETCH` is used, you can end up with duplicated for the entity you're querying. Adding a `DISTINCT` to the JPQL select removes those, so you might want to try adding a distinct to your criteria.

Comment: @maDa : it is my mistake. i create table appointment_student that can't create primary key for 2 field.

Comment: @Kayaman : Thanks for support. it is work after i add `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`